# converting multipage pdf to series of images

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to use ghostscript to convert a multi-page PDF to a multi-page TIFF and am having some difficulty.

The tiff gets created just fine but it's asking me to manually hit enter for each page in the PDF. eg.

```
Page 39
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

This doesn't lend itself well to automation. I didn't see a /force-like option in the man page so...  any ideas as to how I can overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - needed to add `-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH` to the CLI call.